# Fontawesome icon does not show with hyperlink

Tags: css, hyperlink

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ '/assets/css/style.css?v=' | append: site.github.build_revision | relative_url }}">
  <script src="{{ '/assets/js/scale.fix.js' | relative_url }}"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>



[<i class="far fa-link"></i>](https://google.com)
```

I use the markdown as

```
[<i class="far fa-link"></i>] (link)
```

It shows correctly in localhost, but when I upload to github, the icon does not appear  in IE.

The icon without hyperlink works perfectly.

Comment: On IE browser do like this:
Tools >> Internet Options >> Advanced Tab
Then click on the Reset button

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How can I use the icon that is kept in the root directory instead of using fontawsome stylesheet used in the headline? My apologies if it looks naive.

Comment: @Mithun people could give you more helpful advice if you included more code in your post. But, make sure you have the file on the server and that the path to the file is relevant.

Comment: @JaeeunLee I am preparing the Snippet.

Comment: @JaeeunLee Paulie_D. I have added the Snippet.

Comment: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/Css/font-awesome.min.css` is 404 for me. I'm guessing the `Css` should be `css` in that URL

Comment: @j08691 I corrected. /releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css

Comment: you need to use `fas` the `far` is PRO

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for your input. It works.